# Best way to searching in an array of objects, based on given range in numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example, we have an array like

```
var arr = [{'startTime': 0, 'endTime': 2}, 
           {'startTime': 1, 'endTime': 3},
           {'startTime': 4, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 5, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 7, 'endTime': 13},
           {'startTime': 20, 'endTime': 25},
           {'startTime': 27, 'endTime': 32},
           {'startTime': 30, 'endTime': 35},
          ]
```

this array can be of any length, Now if need result of **8** as current  time then we need to search all item where 8 is rely in the range. so result will be

```
           [{'startTime': 4, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 5, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 7, 'endTime': 13},]
```

What is the best way to search this in minimum iterations on the array ?

Comment: Is the array sorted in any way? Your sample has ascending start time

Comment: Unless the array contains millions of entries and you have to save every millisecond possible just go with `.filter()`

Comment: @Meir yes we have sorted array based on start time.

Comment: @Andreas we need check on every millisecond and data will be in millions. .filter() is not a good choice in that case. Right ?

Comment: If there's millions of these objects, it should not be done on the client. Since we're filtering, you can just chunk the array in parts of x elements and filter all of them in parallel on the server. Worst case, do the same client side with a bunch of web workers instead of extra child process'

Comment: what is the range of the time values? What is the min possible startTime and max possible endTime?

Comment: @georg range can be in milliseconds, for 2-3hrs time span.

Answer (score 3):

try like this.

```js
var arr = [{'startTime': 0, 'endTime': 2}, 
           {'startTime': 1, 'endTime': 3},
           {'startTime': 4, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 5, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 7, 'endTime': 13},
           {'startTime': 20, 'endTime': 25},
           {'startTime': 27, 'endTime': 32},
           {'startTime': 30, 'endTime': 35},
          ];

console.log(arr.filter((item, index) => (item.startTime <= 8 && item.endTime >= 8)));
```

Comment: will it not iterate through all the items in array ? I need to iterate on minimum possible values in Array, because this array can have thousands of items and need to check on every second.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a predicate of:

```
item => item.startTime <= value && value <= item.endTime
```

Where `item` is an item of `arr` being filtered, and `value` is the value being tested for containment in the `item`'s range.

This could be expressed in code as:

```js
var arr = [{'startTime': 0, 'endTime': 2}, 
           {'startTime': 1, 'endTime': 3},
           {'startTime': 4, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 5, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 7, 'endTime': 13},
           {'startTime': 20, 'endTime': 25},
           {'startTime': 27, 'endTime': 32},
           {'startTime': 30, 'endTime': 35},
          ];
     
/* Filters items of arr that have a range containing the specified value */
const getItemsContaining = (value) => arr.filter(item => item.startTime <= value && value <= item.endTime)

console.log(getItemsContaining(8))
```

Comment: This is indeed the best way to write conditions like this, for the lack of python's `start < value < end`

Comment: filter will check all the items in array, i need to minimize the iteration on minimum possible items with binary search or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to filter an array:

```js
var arr = [{'startTime': 0, 'endTime': 2}, 
           {'startTime': 1, 'endTime': 3},
           {'startTime': 4, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 5, 'endTime': 9},
           {'startTime': 7, 'endTime': 13},
           {'startTime': 20, 'endTime': 25},
           {'startTime': 27, 'endTime': 32},
           {'startTime': 30, 'endTime': 35},
          ]

console.log(arr.filter(el => el.startTime < 8 && el.endTime > 8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of binary search tree in javascript. You can check it
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-binary-search-tree-javascript/